# hide/collpase "contact form" on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic bootstrap contact form.

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">Phone :</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have long content on the page.
When the current page is opened, the contact form is shown at the front. But when the page is scrolled for more than 100px, I want the contact form to be hidden or collapsed to the right side.
Can a contact form be hidden after page is scrolled more than 100px ? If yes, please tell me how ?
I don't know how to do it.

Comment: [do some research and try something before asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Show your effort please.

Comment: Have a look at .scroll function of jquery https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: I did. I couldn't find answer according to my need, hence I asked.

Comment: @Manishh Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Go through with link which is provided to you [Scroll_on_click](https://jsfiddle.net/hellodeepak007/KFmLv/8423/) ,Hope this will help to you.

```
<div id="body">
<h2>Slide toggle from right to left and left to right.</h2>
    <hr/>
    <p>
        <select class="mySelect">
            <option value="right">Right</option>
            <option value="left">Left</option>            
            <option value="up">Up</option>
            <option value="down">Down</option>
        </select>
        <button id="button" class="animate-btn">Run Effect</button>
    </p>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <div class="container">
            <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone">Phone :</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event to detect scroll. Here is the sample code snippet for scroll event.

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    $('.container').hide();
});
```

when user scrolled to certain height.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        // when scroll to bottom of the page
        $('.container').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. what if I want to hide the container after certain height ? for example : hiding the container when page is scrolled more than 100px. and showing the container back when user touches the footer of the page?

Comment: I got the answer. Thankyou for your efforts.